# Self-tracking entities original values

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Self-tracking entities do not save original properties values. So all properties are marked as modified when you call ApplyChanges. But I need to log the properties which actually changed. I tried to use ApplyOriginalValues, but in this case AcceptChanges throws an exception as finds entities duplicates. Are there any ways to make STE keep original values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/cda357cf-e69b-42d0-88bd-e8a598bad25e

Answer (score 0):

The generated self tracking template is tracking changes, but not saving the original values for properties that are not part of the EntityKey, are not foreign keys or their **ConcurrencyMode**  properties not set to **Fixed**.

I needed to enable this value tracking for one of my properties, so I decided to set its ConcurrencyMode property to Fixed so it tracks the original value now.

The side effect of this change is that the generated UPDATE SQL statement will contain a check for the original value of this property in its WHERE clause.